# How can get an image from an image view?

Tags: android, sql, database, image

I am trying to get an image that I put into an image view. This is my approach:

```
// Get the image in the image view
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Bitmap myBitmap = mImageView.getDrawingCache();
    myBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);
```

Then I want to insert it into a database:

```
mDbHelper.createReminder(outputStream);
```

The DatabaseAdapter looks like this:

```
public long createReminder(ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_IMAGE, outputStream.toByteArray());        
    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
```

When I tried it the app crashed. I think that my statements are somehow faulty. Any ideas???

Comment: Could you add any Log trace?
More, add a picture in a database is a very bad idea

Comment: yes, but can you see any logic problems??

Comment: ok, but is it possible to get an image from an image view, convert it and store it as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Drawable drawable = mImageView.getDrawable();
if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
    Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
}
```

Comment: this is how I get the image from an image view??

Comment: check for null object, in order to avoid NPE

Answer (score 1):

```
Drawable myDrawable = mImageView.getDrawable();

Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)myDrawable).getBitmap();
```

now you convert bitmap into stream and store in db.